# Decimal precision in JSON Schema

Tags: json, rest, jsonschema

I want to have my JSON Schema validate that no more than two decimal places are sent to my REST API.

From what I can see in the latest JSON Schema RFC (v4) doesn't allow this. V1 had a maxDecimals validator.

Does anyone know why that was taken out?

I have a field that only holds two decimals when I store it in the database, and I do not just want to round down to two decimals. That would be changing the input quite dramatically for some users. So I want to reject any greater precision and force them to round themselves.

I can of course do this using a custom validator that I write myself, but I would rather not unless I have to.

Is there another way of indicating this in v4?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They replaced it with multipleOf (via v3 divisibleBy).

For 2 decimal places, just add multipleOf: 0.01.

Comment: Hmmm... then integers aren't accepted. Integer 5 is not evenly divisible by 0.01.

Comment: Then you might be using a faulty json-schema validator.  Which validator did you use, and did you go with v3 divisibleBy or v4 multipleOf?

Comment: Try this on http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/

Schema:
{
  "type": "integer",
  "multipleOf": 0.01
}

Data:
5

Comment: I use Newtonsoft.Json for .NET, It only supports v3. And the schema that you have given in your example should be { "type": "number", "multipleOf": 0.01 } to also allow 5.12. When I read the documentation and unit tests for NewtonSoft, it behaves as intended.

Comment: Due to floating point imprecision, this is not reliable, e.g. 147.41 will pass validation, but 147.42 will not https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/issues/158

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest using `{ "type": "number", "multipleOf": 0.01 }` rather than `{ "type": "integer", "multipleOf": 0.01 }`.

See http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#multiples

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string with a regex pattern.
Based on [JSON Schema specification rfc.section.6.3](http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.6.3):

```json
{ 
  "type": "string", 
  "pattern": "^-?\\d*(.\\d{0,2})?$" 
}
```

Comment: I think that your regex would allow `42.` as value: the capturing group allows zero decimal places after the dot. I'd think that, when the (optional) group is given, at least one decimal place should follow the dot, so I'd go for `-?^\\d*(.\\d{1,2})?$`.

Comment: You shouldn't use strings for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use python jsonschema library than you need

```
{ "type": "number", "multipleOfPrecision": 0.01 }
```

https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#options

Comment: `multipleOfPrecision` is not valid to use, it does not exist in the JSON Schema specification. Refer to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/python-jsonschema/jsonschema/issues/1039) for more information