# How can I denote decimal floating point in swagger specs?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I would like to denote decimal with 2 places and decimal with 1 place in my api documentation. I'm using swagger 2.0, Is there inbuilt defined type or any other 'round' parameter in the specs, or my only option is to use 'x-' extension?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OpenAPI (fka Swagger) Specification uses a subset of [JSON Schema](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/) to describe the data types.

If the parameter is passed as a number, you can try using `multipleOf` as suggested in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27260587/113116):

```yaml
type: number
multipleOf: 0.1     # up to 1 decimal place,  e.g. 4.2
# multipleOf: 0.01  # up to 2 decimal places, e.g. 4.25
```

Hovewer, `multipleOf` validation against floating-point numbers can be unreliable due to [floating-point math specifics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/113116).

If your number if passed as a string, you can specify a regex `pattern` for the desired number format:

```yaml
type: string
pattern: your_regex
```

In any case, you can also document any restrictions verbally in the `description`.

Comment: in java, `type: number` will convert to `BigDecimal`

Comment: @Hariom Yadav , which Java library are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it myself, but try to create a Java wrapper, annnotate the wrapped field with your desired annotations (in this case, @Digits might help you), provide `@Getter` and `@Setter` with lombok, then use importMappings and typeMappings to use your custom wrapper.

For example:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyWrapper {
    @Digits(integer = 1, fraction = 8)
    private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
}
```

In pom.xml file, using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`.

```xml
    <importMappings>
        <importMapping>MyWrapper=my.package.MyWrapper</importMapping>
    </importMappings>
    <typeMappings>
        <typeMapping>number+digits=MyWrapper</typeMapping>
    </typeMappings>
```

In your yaml file:

```yml
    properties:
      myProperty:
        type: number
        format: digits
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35023991)